# About Hahn-Banach Theorem assumption

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, number-theory, additive-combinatorics, hahn-banach-theorem

Currently I am trying to understand the proof of the following lemma which appear in the book Additive combinatorics of Tao and Vu (Chapter 5, page 212, in the 2006 edition).

**Lemma 5.14**
Let $A, B$ be additive sets in a finite-dimensional vector space
$V$ such that $A$ and $B$ both contain $0$, and suppose that $0$ is a vertex on the convex hull
of $A \cup B$. Let $A^{\prime} := A \setminus \{0\}$ and $B^{\prime}:= B \setminus \{0\}$, and $C := (A^{\prime} \cup B^{\prime} )\setminus(A^{\prime} + B^{\prime})$.
Then $A + B=\lbrace a+b:a\in A, b\in B\rbrace$ lies in the subspace of $V$ spanned by $C$.

In the proof of the theorem the book start the proof as follows

**Proof**

Without loss of generality we may take $V = \mathbb{R}^n$ . By the Hahn–Banach
theorem, there exists a linear functional $\varphi : V → \mathbb{R}$ such that $\varphi(x) > 0$ for all
$x \in (A \cup B)\setminus \{0\}$. We need to show that every element $x$ of $A + B$ lies in the span
of C. We shall prove this by induction on $\varphi(x)$, which is a non-negative integer.

In this first part of the proof I have two questions.

**Question 1**. Why we can assume that $\varphi(x)$ is an integer ?
My ideas are the following. Since $\varphi:\mathbb{R^n}\to \mathbb{R}$ we already know that $\varphi$ should have the form $\varphi(x_1,\ldots, x_n)=\sum_{j=1}^n \alpha_jx_j$ for $\alpha_j\in \mathbb{R}$ and from here I think that we can do a suitable transformation in the $\alpha_j$ to obtain an integer (but this does not clear to me).

**Question 2**. How to apply the Hanh-Banach theorem in this case? This is the principal problem. I understand that the theorem say that we can extend a linear functional $g:M\to \mathbb{R}$ dominated by a seminorm $\psi:V\to \mathbb{R}$ to a linear functional $f:V\to \mathbb{R}$ such that $f\mid_M=g$ and $f\leq \psi$ for all $x \in V$. Frome here I do not understand which subspace $M$ is taken.

Any hints or answers are welcome.

Comment: $A$ and $B$ are finite, if I understand the context of the book correctly?

Comment: yes, A and B are finite. In fact, a set  $A$ is additive if is not empty and finite,

Comment: I feel like the Hahn-Banach used here is one of the geometric versions, the ones that separate convex sets, [among these versions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hahn%E2%80%93Banach_theorem#Geometric_Hahn%E2%80%93Banach_(the_Hahn%E2%80%93Banach_separation_theorems)).

Comment: I also try using the geometric version, but unfortunately, I can not deduce the assumption from here.

Comment: @BrunoB Can you explain to me the more simple version of the Geometric Hahn-Banach theorem? I did read the Wikipedia version, but I do not understand it well, and this may be the problem for which I can not deduce this easy consequence.

Comment: I have no clue about the integer/induction part, but here they seem to use the "compact-closed" geometric Hahn-Banach (the second one in the box that has "If
$X$ is complex (rather than real) (blahblah)") on the sets $\{0\}$ compact convex and $\mathrm{Conv}((A \cup B) \setminus \{0\})$, convex closed because of the finiteness of $A$ and $B$, which is disjoint from $\{0\}$ thanks to the vertex assumption I believe. I can't make sense of the induction for now though.

Comment: Thanks a lot for you clarification about the Hahn-Banach theorem. I will reading the geometric version in order of clarify your ideas about this part of the proof.